# How to fix Error: useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-router-dom, react-testing-library

How do I resolve this problem. I am just trying to create a test the ensures that that component renders, but for some reason keep getting this problem even though the component is already inside `<Router>`.

I have read other similar questions on here, and the answers all say to put the component inside the `<Router/>`, But that doesn't seem to be the issue for me. Please tell me what it is I'm missing?

** My app.tsx**

```
import './App.scss';
import { AuthContexProvider } from './Utils/Contexs/AuthContext';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { LogoLarge } from './Components/Logo/Logo';
import { SignInView } from './Views/SignInView';
import { ErrorPage } from './Views/ErrorView';
import { SignUpView } from './Views/SignUpView';
import { SwipeView } from './Views/SwipeView';
import { ResetPasswordView } from './Views/ResetPasswordView';
import { CreateProfileView } from './Views/CreateProfileView';
import { PrivateRoute } from './Utils/PrivateRoute';
import { ProfileView } from './Views/ProfileView';
import { SwipeContexProvider } from './Utils/Contexs/SwipeContex';
import { MatchesView } from './Views/MatchesView';
import { MessageView } from './Views/MessageView';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <AuthContexProvider>
        <SwipeContexProvider>
          <header className='appWrapper'>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<PrivateRoute component={SwipeView} />} />
              <Route
                path='/signin'
                element={
                  <div className='signInViewWrapper'>
                    <nav>
                      <LogoLarge />
                    </nav>
                    <SignInView />
                  </div>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path='/signup'
                element={
                  <div className='signUpViewWrapper'>
                    <nav>
                      <LogoLarge />
                    </nav>
                    <SignUpView />
                  </div>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path='/resetpassword'
                element={
                  <div className='resetPasswordViewWrapper'>
                    <nav>
                      <LogoLarge />
                    </nav>
                    <ResetPasswordView />
                  </div>
                }
              />
              <Route path='/createprofile' element={<PrivateRoute component={CreateProfileView} />} />
              <Route path='/profile' element={<PrivateRoute component={ProfileView} />} />
              <Route path='/matches' element={<PrivateRoute component={MatchesView} />} />
              <Route path='/matches/:id' element={<PrivateRoute component={MessageView} />} />
              <Route
                path='*'
                element={
                  <div className='appContent'>
                    <ErrorPage />
                  </div>
                }
              />
            </Routes>
          </header>
        </SwipeContexProvider>
      </AuthContexProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**SignUpView**

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SignUpForm } from '../Components/Forms/SignUpForm';

//SASS
// import '../Styles/Scss/SignUpView.scss';
import { StyledFormsWrapper } from '../Styles/StyledComponents/StyledFormsWrapper';

export const SignUpView = () => {
  return (
    <StyledFormsWrapper data-testid='todo-1' className='signUpWrapper'>
      <Typography className='actionTitle' variant='h5' gutterBottom component='div' sx={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>
        Create account
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant='subtitle1' gutterBottom component='div'>
        Already have an account? <Link to={'/signin'}>Sign in</Link>
      </Typography>
      <SignUpForm />
    </StyledFormsWrapper>
  );
};
```

**SignUpView.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { SignUpView } from '../../Views/SignUpView';

describe('my function or component', () => {
  test('Should render sigUp view component', () => {
    render(<SignUpView />);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `SignUpView` is missing a routing context in your test. Import a memory router and wrap the component under test so it has a provided routing context.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SignUpView } from '../../Views/SignUpView';

describe('my function or component', () => {
  test('Should render sigUp view component', () => {
    render(
      <Router>
        <SignUpView />
      </Router>
    );
  });
});
```

In fact, this pattern of needing to provide context is so common that RTL has a [`wrapper`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#wrapper) option you can use to provider a wrapper component that provides all the contexts a component uses, i.e. routing, themes, redux, locale translations, etc...

Example:

```
const RouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <MemoryRouter>
    {children}
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

...

```
import { RouterWrapper } from '../path/to/RouterWrapper';

describe('my function or component', () => {
  test('Should render sigUp view component', () => {
    render(<SignUpView />, { wrapper: RouterWrapper });
  });
});
```

See [custom render](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render) for more details.

Answer (score 24):

for tests you can provide a container wrapper

```
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

test('Should render sigUp view component', () => {
  render(<SignUpView />, {wrapper: MemoryRouter});
});
```

[this link has some useful examples](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/#reducing-boilerplate)